# Is this a correct way to approximate a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have some function $S(\hat y)$ which I want to approximate its derivative with respect to a vector. It's a tad complicated, I'll try and explain.

$S$ is a function of $\hat y$ only, but $\hat y$ is a function of many different variables, one of which is called $w_2$. I want to calculate $\frac{\partial S}{\partial w_2}$

How it works:

We are given $w_1 \in \mathbb R^{m \times d}$, $w_2 \in \mathbb R^{k \times m}$, $b_1 \in \mathbb R^{m\times 1}$, $b2 \in \mathbb R^{k \times 1}$, $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}$ and $y \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$

$\hat y$ **which we are interested in** is calculated as follows:

define $z_1 = w_1X^T+\begin{bmatrix}b_1 & b_1 & \dots & b_1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. we just replicated the vector $b_1$ $n$ times and shoved them in a matrix.

Now define $h = g(z_1) \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ where $g$ is some known function, not important or exciting.

now define (nearly done) $z_2 = (w_2h+\begin{bmatrix} b_2 & b_2 & \dots & b_2\end{bmatrix})^T \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$ where again, we just replicated $b_2$ $n$ times and put it in a matrix form.

Finally, we have $\hat y = P(z_2)$. where $P$ is again some known function. So $\hat y$ is a function of $w_2$ in a very subtle manner, and so is $S$.

I'd like to know if this is a correct way to **approximate the derivative** of $S$ with respect to $w_2$ at index $(i,j)$:

1) do everything the same. Do not change a thing until you reach the part where you calculate $z_2$.

2) define ${w_2}^+$ and ${w_2}^-$ which are identical to $w_2$, except for index $i,j$. in ${w_2}^+$ we added $\epsilon$ to index $i,j$ and in ${w_2}^-$ we subtracted $\epsilon$.

3) continue everything as normal, compute ${z_2}^+$ and ${z_2}^-$ and ${\hat y}^+$ and ${\hat y}^-$.

4) The derivative at $i,j$ is approximately $\frac{S({\hat y}^+)-S({\hat y}^-)}{2\epsilon}$

Is this a correct way to numerically approximate the derivative?